# Arguments to function not getting passed in correctly MASM

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I'm learning MASM and I can't get this simple code to work. I'm not getting the values I pass into invoke, I don't know what's happening. I've tried push 2, push 2, call pow. Same results. EAX and EDX look like garbage or maybe memory addresses.

The thread 0x1544 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0xd8 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x898 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The thread 0x21c4 has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).
The program '[2296] AssemblyTutorial.exe' has exited with code -1073741510 (0xc000013a).

This just means I closed the console window, but why are there 4 threads?

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include windows.inc

include masm32.inc
includelib masm32.lib

include kernel32.inc
includelib kernel32.lib

include user32.inc
includelib user32.lib


.code

;requires power > 0 for correct answers
pow proc x:DWORD, power:DWORD

    ;THESE TWO MOVES RIGHT HERE ARE NOT WORKING AS EXPECTED
    ;I PUSH 2 ONTO STACK BUT WHEN I LOOK AT REGISTER VALUES
    ;IN DEBUG THEY ARE INCORRECT/GARBAGE
    mov eax, x      ;eax has x
    mov edx, power  ;edx has power
    mov ecx, eax    ;ecx will be my constant base

start_power:
    cmp edx, 1      ;is power 1?
    je end_power    ;then jump to end
    imul eax, ecx   ;else mul result/x with x
    dec edx         ;power--
    jmp start_power ;jump back to beginning of loop

end_power:
    ret             ;return answer eax

pow endp


start:

invoke pow, 2, 2 ;eax should hold 4 after this
invoke ExitProcess, eax ;program should exit with code eax, ez way to print result

end start
```

Comment: Do I have to manage the stack pointer and base pointer myself with stdcall? I'm under the impression that masm proc does that for you.

Comment: You can edit your own post instead of adding comments to elaborate on your question.

Comment: IMUL always puts results in EDX? I don't understand what EDX:EAX means either. What does it mean when you put a colon in between like that?

Comment: "The three forms of the IMUL instruction are similar in that the length of the product is calculated to twice the length of the operands. With the one-operand form, the product is stored exactly in the destination. With the two- and three- operand forms, however, the result is truncated to the length of the destination before it is stored in the destination register. Because of this truncation, the CF or OF flag should be tested to ensure that no significant bits are lost."

So the results will get truncated and not span multiple registers. The result will be in EAX. No?

Comment: Your right. Apologies. My assumption was wrong.

Comment: When I debug, EDX decrements by 1 consistently so it is not being overwritten, at least I think. lol

All good, this shit gets complicated lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the difference between cdecl and stdcall is that the former is caller-clean and the latter is callee-clean. (See also [Raymond Chen's series on calling conventions in Windows](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040108-00/?p=41163).

The problem is, your `pow` procedure was *not* following the stdcall convention because it was *not* cleaning the stack. You need to specify the number of bytes to pop as part of the `ret` instruction. In this case, that would be `ret 8`.

Or, you can make the function cdecl, in which case the caller becomes responsible for cleaning the stack, and MASM can automatically generate this code as part of the `INVOKE` directive.

> why are there 4 threads?

Windows starts background threads for various reasons. These are nothing to worry about. If you investigate them further, you'll probably see that they're started by the thread-pool worker thread (`TppWorkerThread` in ntdll.dll).

---

For what it's worth, the `pow` function could be more efficiently written as:

```
pow PROC x:DWORD, power:DWORD
    ; Load parameters into registers
    mov  eax, x
    mov  edx, power
    mov  ecx, eax

    ; Decrement 'power' by 1 and bail out if we're done.
    dec  edx
    jz   Finished

    ; The main loop.
CalculatePow:
    imul eax, ecx
    dec  edx
    jnz  CalculatePow

Finished:
    ret  8        ; assuming this function is STDCALL
pow ENDP
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Lots of good info in that post! I wasn't aware dec set the zero flag like that. Good stuff. I didn't know c stands for cdecl either lol. Do invoke and ret change their behavior to match the calling convention? I never see people clean the stack, set the base pointer, or any of that good stuff in MASM code.

Comment: @user Yes, the "c" in cdecl refers to the C language because this is the standard calling convention in C. Windows didn't use it, because you can save a few bytes by having the callee clean up the stack, which is what stdcall does. The "std" means standard in Windows. It is based on an earlier calling convention from 16-bit Windows called "pascal" because that's what the Pascal language uses. I don't know what MASM code you've been looking at, but *all* of the code I see cleans the stack. Then again, I don't use `invoke` much because it isn't portable to other assemblers.

Comment: Yes, `INVOKE` automatically handles pushing and popping arguments according to the calling convention. *But* it doesn't affect the `RET` instruction within a function's implementation, so stdcall functions still need to clean up the stack themselves by doing `ret x`, where `x` is the number of bytes to pop. The number of bytes to pop is an *optional* argument to [`RET`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_280.html). It is used for stdcall functions, but not for cdecl functions. With a cdecl function, `INVOKE` will handle cleaning the stack because the cleanup is done caller-side.

Comment: I checked the disassembly of my program, changing the calling convention to stdcall, and the compiler is using `ret 8` in place of my `ret` when I use invoke. I also verified that it is setting the base pointer up correctly for me. I don't understand why my code wasn't working before lol.

Comment: Huh. Maybe I'm wrong and `INVOKE` *does* change the code output. I didn't know that. There's no good documentation for `INVOKE` online; you have to go back to [old MASM 6 manuals](http://people.sju.edu/~ggrevera/arch/references/MASM61PROGUIDE.pdf). The examples there only show `INVOKE` being used with cdecl functions, *but* it does say that if you are using automatic prologue/epilogue code with the `PROC` directive, and you use a `RET` instruction with no operand, then the assembler will automatically append the correct number of bytes. So that's probably what's doing it, not `INVOKE`.

Comment: See pg. 159: *"The assembler generates standard epilogue code when it encounters a RET instruction without an operand. It does not generate an epilogue if RET has a nonzero operand. To suppress generation of a standard epilogue, use RETN or RETF with or without an operand, or use RET 0."* Honestly, I try to avoid overly complicated macros in assembly. They just make the code less readable, as far as I'm concerned, since there's a bunch of magic happening behind the scenes. If I wanted that, I'd be programming in C!

Comment: "If I wanted that, I'd be programming in C!" - agreed. All this craziness is just making it harder for me to learn. Ty for your help and insights!

Comment: @user8210143 and Cody: Why exactly did `pow` get bad values for its args with the calling convention mismatch, according to comments about using a debugger?  Stack-cleaning differences should only result in a crash after returning, and I don't see any other differences mentioned in this answer or Raymond's article.  I don't have MASM installed or I'd just assemble it and *look at the disassembly output to see what magic happened behind my back*.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I've no idea why `pow` was reading bad values there, either. I couldn't reproduce that in my own tests, and I can only assume it was caused by calling the function a second time with a corrupted stack. The disassembly output (`/Sa /Flfilename.lst` options in MASM) is exactly what you'd expect. It pushes 2 onto the stack twice, and calls `pow`. At the top of `pow` is the standard prologue: `push ebp`+`mov ebp, esp`+`mov eax, [ebp+8]`+`mov edx, [ebp+12]`+etc. It *doesn't* get `ret` right, though—that is, it doesn't transform it into `ret 8`, which goes to the corrupted stack theory.

Comment: [Here is a Pastebin of what MASM generates for the original code in the question](https://pastebin.com/idfyQt0U), in case my wordy description was less than clear. I omitted the Irvine32 lib stuff, because I don't have that installed. That wouldn't change the relevant bits, though.

Comment: Ah ok.  I thought this answer was claiming to explain that part of the question.  If it's not, then it was probably some kind of beginner error that saw that in the first place, since neither of us thinks it's possible.  (@user8210143: correct us if we're wrong :P)

Comment: When I watch the registers and step through the disassembly a non-register address pops up in the register window with a ~random value after 2 is moved into eax inside the pow function, next step should put 2 into edx, but it puts the ~random value from the non-register address gets moved into edx instead. The disassembly itself looks the way it should I think.

Answer (score 0):

Change the calling convention to c and it works, but I don't know why. If someone could explain that would be great.

With stdcall calling convention the callee cleans up the stack... and that's all I know. There must be more to it. The stack pointer could just carry on at whatever position after returning from the pow function and things should work correctly right?